# How to set the active tab's tab color in Iterm2?

Tags: iterm2

I often use Iterm2's multiple-tabs feature.
[image]

The problem is that the TAB color of an active TAB does not contrast strongly with the TAB color of other inactive tabs.

I can manually set the tab color of any of the tabs, like this,
[image]

Is there a way to automatically set the tab color of the current active tab?
This way I can easily know which TAB I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

Colors can be changed in profiles section:

[image]

Unfortunately it changes (slightly) background of all tabs as well wich is a bit counterproductive.
Perhaps you can try contrasting text and outline of the active tab like here (advanced section in settings):

[image]

It looks like this (with my color theme):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use [escape codes](https://iterm2.com/documentation-escape-codes.html) to set the colors, see examples and helpful info at   https://superuser.com/questions/403650/programmatically-set-the-color-of-a-tab-in-iterm2